# Saben cómo encontrar la fuente del id de un div?

Tags: php, html, sql-server, div, id

Estoy revisando un proyecto que NO empecé yo, en una parte del proyecto hay una pagina que muestra datos de un BD en una tabla. El detalle es que esta implementado con una etiqueta **div** algo asi...

```
<body>
  <div id="datos"></div>
</body>
```

Si modifico la palabra **datos**, ya no se muestra la tabla y me hace pensar que el contenido esta en un arhivo **js**. Alguien sabe como encontrar esa fuente "**datos**"? Las conexiones a la BD es en php con SQLServer. Revisando la parte de los scripts de la vista, tiene agregada un script de **Google**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Ya revise que si comento o elimino esa etiqueta script la tabla desaparece.

Comment: Pulsa F12 en tu navegador con esa página abierta, vete a la pestaña "Depurador" y alli realiza una búsqueda global (Control+Shift+F) de la palabra **datos**, y a ver que encuentras (eso el Firefox). Si estás en Chrome pulsa F12, vete a Sources (Fuentes) y pulsa el boton derecho sobre el primer elemento del arbol **Top** que mostrará una opción emergente que pone "Search in all files" y lo mismo. Suerte

Comment: Haz lo que te he dicho antes. Lo que acabas de poner tan solo indica que seguramente el div **datos** se rellena con jquery, pero al desactivarlo como has hecho pues ya no.  Esto te puede ayudar a encontrarlo, pues en lugar de buscar **datos** como te he explicado antes (y que quizas te salen muchos) podrias buscar `$('#datos')` o quizás `$("#datos")` o simplemente `#datos` para encontrar el script que lo llena entre todos los que ha cargado la página

Comment: Por cierto, esa versión de jquery es del año 2011.. solo hace 11 años, je

Comment: `grep -nir datos`